# Regexp replace any single word

Tags: javascript, regex, regexp-replace

I need to replace 'page.a = b' with 'page.a = node.b'. In a word, i need to turn single word 'b' into 'node.b'; In other word, the string 'page.a = b && page.a < c' shold be transformed into 'page.a = node.b && page.a < node.c', just add 'node.' as the prefix to the single words. Can anyone help me with this? I think the js regexp can work but just cannot find the way with it.

```
let origin = 'page.a = b'
let expected = 'page.a = node.b';
```

How do i get the expected string from the origin ?

Comment: What is the criteria for words that should be replaced? Any word that isn't preceded by `page.`?

Comment: Or a word that isn't preceded by `.`?

Comment: Either way, you should be able to use a negative lookbehind to match what you want. Also use `\b` word boundaries to match the whole word.

Comment: Actually, i want any single word can be replaced with 'node.' prefix. For example, const origin = 'age > 14 && page.num > num && page.name.includes(name)'; I want it to turn it into:   'node.age > 14 && page.num > node.num && page.name.includes(node.name)' ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negative lookarounds to look for words that aren't preceded by or followed by a dot or a word character:

```
(?<![.\w])(\w+)(?![.\w])
```

and replace the matching words with:

```
node.$1
```

https://regex101.com/r/GD2N9g/5

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach:

#### Logic:

- Split string using equals to(`=`) to get LHS and RHS as this operation only needs to be done on RHS.
- Create a regex to match any word + period combination. You can also use non-space characters(`/[\s]+/`) as this will cover bracket notations and underscore as well
- For each match, check if they do not have period(`.`) in it. If not, you can append prefix and return it.
- Join both halves and return the string

```js
let origin = 'page.a = b'
let o1 = 'page.a = b && page.a < c'

function transformStr(str, prefix) {
  const regex = /([\w.]+)/g;
  const [lhs, rhs] = str.split('=')
  const newRhs = rhs.replace(regex, (part) => {
    return /^\w+$/.test(part) ? `${prefix}.${part}` : part
  })
  return `${lhs}=${newRhs}`
}

console.log(transformStr(origin, 'node'))
console.log(transformStr(o1, 'node'))
```

As an extension, you can add support for special characters that can exists in a variable. This approach matches non-spaced character groups and processes only the ones that has only word characters or underscore or dollar

```js
function transformStr(str, prefix) {
  const regex = /([^\s]+)/g;
  const [lhs, rhs] = str.split('=')
  const newRhs = rhs.replace(regex, (part) => {
    return /^[\w\$]+$/.test(part) ? `${prefix}.${part}` : part
  })
  return `${lhs}=${newRhs}`
}

console.log(transformStr('page.a = b', 'node'))
console.log(transformStr('page.a = b && page.a < c', 'node'))
console.log(transformStr('page._a = _b && page.a < $c', 'node'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention. Actually, the str can be any javascript expression. It is highly possible that the '=' does not appear. For example, the string is 'test > page.b && page.age < test && page.name.includes(abc)'. The result i want is 'node.test > page.b && page.age < node.test && page.name.includes(node.abc)'. I think regexp may work but just could not find the way with it